# Can't comprehend the Laravel "Get column names" function output

Tags: sql, arrays, laravel

I used the [following answer to get the desired results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733254/get-column-names-in-laravel-as-ordered-on-the-table). However, I can't understand this resulted array/collection and make one dimensional array of it. This is my result:

```
array:2 [
  "health" => array:115 [
    0 => {#1340 ▼
      +"column_name": "id"
    }
    1 => {#1325 ▶}
    2 => {#1346 ▼
      +"column_name": "name"
    }
    3 => {#1347 ▼
      +"column_name": "sex"
    }
  ]
```

I used the following but getting:

```php
$cols = $cols[0]['column_name'];  //result Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
$cols = $cols[0]{'column_name'};  //result Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Comment: Objects and arrays have different syntax. Arrays are accessed like `['column_name']`, Objects are accessed like `->column_name`. Your error is telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: What's the command you used to show array...? Please show all the result of this cde.